# Find the laurent series for $\frac{1}{z(z-2)^2}$ centered at z=2 and specify the region in which it converges.

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

**My attempt:**

$$\frac{1}{z(z-2)^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{z(z-2)^2} = \frac{A}{z}+\frac{B}{z-2}+\frac{C}{(z-2)^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{z(z-2)^2} = \frac{(1/4)}{z}+\frac{(-1/4)}{z-2}+\frac{(1/2)}{(z-2)^2}$$

This is where I get stuck. The general idea I know is to get each of the 3 terms above into the form $D\cdot \frac{1}{1-z}$, where $D$ is a constant. But for the first term, it would be $\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{(0-z)}$. I can't get rid of the zero.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Write $\frac1z$ as

$$\frac1z=\frac{1/2}{1+(z-2)/2}$$

Then, recall the sum of a geometric series.

---

**SPOILER ALERT:** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> $$\begin{align}\frac1z&=\frac{1}{2+(z-2)}\\\\&=\frac{1/2}{1+(z-2)/2}\\\\&=\frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{z-2}{2}\right)^n\end{align}$$for $|z-2|<2$.  Therefore, the Laurent series is given by $$\frac12 (z-2)^{-2}-\frac14 (z-2)^{-1}+\frac18 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{z-2}{2}\right)^n=\frac18\sum_{n=-2}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{z-2}{2}\right)^n$$

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Markus, not at all.  I appreciate another pair of eyes on this.  The hazards of "cutting and pasting" are evident here.  Thanks much again!  - Mark

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for your nice reply! :-)

Comment: Based on your answer, are you saying that the series converges in the region $|z-2|<2$? What about $|z-2|>2$?

Comment: Yes, this is the series for $|z-2|<2$.  When $|z-2|>2$, write $$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{z-2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z-2}}$$and proceed analogously.  Please let me know if this helps. - Mark

Answer (score 0):

Let $\zeta = z - 2$. We are trying to find the Laurent series for $1/(\zeta+2)\zeta^2$ centred at $\zeta = 0$, so
$$ f = \frac{1}{(\zeta+2)\zeta^2} = \zeta^{-2} \frac{1}{\zeta + 2}
$$
The latter is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $0$, so let $(a_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ such that
$$ \frac{1}{\zeta + 2} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j \zeta^j, 1 = 2\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j \zeta^j + \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j \zeta^{j+1}
$$
Therefore,
$$ 1 = 2a_0 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty 2a_j \zeta^j + \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{j-1} \zeta^j = 2a_0 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty (2a_j + a_{j-1}) \zeta^j 
$$
so $a_0 = \frac{1}{2}$, and we establish the recurrence relation $a_{j+1} = -\frac{1}{2}a_j$. Hence $a_j = (-1/2)^j$.
The original series becomes
$$ \zeta^{-2} \frac{1}{\zeta + 2} = \zeta^{-2} \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-\frac{1}{2})^j \zeta^j
$$
Then substitute $\zeta = z-2$.

To find the region of convergence, notice that $f$ is holomorphic except at the poles $z = 0, z = 2$. The result follows easily from Laurent's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

> The function
>
> \begin{align*}
>  f(z)&=\frac{1}{z(z-2)^2} = \frac{1}{4z}-\frac{1}{4(z-2)}+\frac{1}{2(z-2)^2}\\
> \end{align*}
>    has a simple pole at $z=0$ and a pole of order two at $z=2$.
>
> Since we want to find a Laurent expansion with center $2$, we look at *the other* pole $0$ and see we have to distinguish *two* regions.
>
> \begin{align*}
>  0<|z-2|<2\qquad\quad\text{and}\qquad\qquad
>  2<|z-2|
>  \end{align*}
>
> - The first region $ |z-2|<2$ is a disc with center $2$, radius $2$ and the pole $0$ at the boundary of the disc. In the *interior* of this disc the fraction with pole $0$ admits a representation as *power series* at $z=2$, while the fractions with pole $2$ admit  a representation  as principal part of a Laurent series at $z=2$.
> - The second region $|z-2|>2$ containing all points *outside* the disc with center $2$ and radius $2$ admits for all fractions a representation as principal part of a Laurent series at $z=2$.

A power series expansion of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=2$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z+a}&=\frac{1}{(a+2)+(z-2)}=\frac{1}{a+2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-2}{a+2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{a+2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{z-2}{a+2}\right)^n\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(a+2)^{n+1}}(z-2)^n\tag{2}
\end{align*}
The principal part of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=2$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z+a}&=\frac{1}{(z-2)+(a+2)}=\frac{1}{z-2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{a+2}{z-2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{z-2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{a+2}{z-2}\right)^n\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(a+2)^n\frac{1}{(z-2)^{n+1}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}(a+2)^{n-1}\frac{1}{(z-2)^{n}}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> We can now obtain the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ at $z=2$ for both regions
>
> - *Region:* $|z-2|<2$
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(z)&= \frac{1}{4z}-\frac{1}{4(z-2)}+\frac{1}{2(z-2)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2+(z-2)}-\frac{1}{4(z-2)}+\frac{1}{2(z-2)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}(z-2)^n-\frac{1}{4(z-2)}+\frac{1}{2(z-2)^2}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=-2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}(z-2)^n
> \end{align*}
>
> - *Region:* $2<|z-2|$
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(z)&=\frac{1}{4z}-\frac{1}{4(z-2)}+\frac{1}{2(z-2)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(z-2)+2}-\frac{1}{4(z-2)}+\frac{1}{2(z-2)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}2^{n-1}\frac{1}{(z-2)^n}-\frac{1}{4(z-2)}+\frac{1}{2(z-2)^2}\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}2^{n}\frac{1}{(z-2)^n}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)*
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{1+z}=\frac{1}{1-(-z)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-z)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nz^n\qquad\qquad |z|<1
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we apply the series expansion of (2)
- In (5) we apply the principal part representation of (3)

Comment: In the section "A power series representation of $\frac{1}{z+a}$..." how did you pull out a $(-1)^n$ and get $=\frac{1}{a+2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\frac{z-2}{a-2})$??

Comment: Shouldn't it be $=\frac{1}{a+2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\frac{z-2}{-a-2})$?

Comment: Actually, in that section *and* the one below it, you have a $(-1)^n$ in the sum but I'm not sure where they came from.

Comment: Also, how did you come to your initial statement that *"Since we want to find a Laurent expansion with center $2$, we look at the other pole $0$ and see we have to distinguish two regions."*